# Cannot find module PIL in Python

Tags: module, python-imaging-library, python-3.7

I am using:

Thonny Version 3.2.1

Python Version 3.7.0

PIP Version 19.2.3
Pillow Version 6.1.0

I am trying to import an image into my program and show it on the screen with the below code:

I get the error:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
backend.py, line 276

I believe the problem isn't my code, but instead an issue with the module Pillow not being found by Python?

Can anyone please help with a fix? I can clarify any info needed.

Additionally, I am new to Python and so go easy on me :-) Apologies if any of my terminology is incorrect.

I have tried:

1\ Removing PIL as per the install warning from Pillow (PIL Fork) install info. It was not present on my system. I did this through CMD.

2\ I always access CMD as the administrator.

3\ Updating all program versions above through CMD.

4\ Info I’ve found shows the above versions are compatible.

5\ Using the code help('modules') to show available modules, it does not show 'PIL' or 'Image', but does show 'pip'.

6\ Checked many forums for other fixes.

from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("JC.png")
im.show()

Comment: How did you install Pillow? Do you happen to have several Python interpreters in your system? By default Thonny uses the packages that are installed into its own private bundled Python (use Tools => Manage packages for this). You can configure it to use another Python if you wish (Tools => Interpreter).

Comment: Thanks for your response. I installed it through CMD (administrator) using the command "PIP Install Pillow". I have only Thonny installed and are only using that.

Comment: I have spent over 5 hours trying to fix this. I went to tools, manage packages, installed pillow as you advised and it worked. THANKS SO MUCH!!